# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles' error to adding a role

Tags: python, discord.py

When I used the script:

```py
@bot.command()
async def agree(ctx):
  await ctx.author.send('Thank you for reading the Terms of Use, you should have access to the server now! (If you have not been given access please contact one of the staff members)')

  var = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Pogchamp")
  ctx.author.add_roles(var)
```

Error :

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It seems like `ctx` is `NoneObject`. Are you sure you pass something to the function? The problem may lie outside of the function.

Comment: @JakubSzlaur: I think `ctx.guild` is `None`, because `ctx.author` was ok

Comment: Ah my bad true ...

Comment: Hm, so should i replace the ctx.author with something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'` occurs due to the statement not being awaited.

This is the section with adding the user's role

```
  ctx.author.add_roles(var)
```

This can simply be corrected to:

```
  await ctx.author.add_roles(var)
```

If you also wanted to specify the role from the command, this can be used with `role: discord.Role = None` then awaiting the member author the role they set, but in this case it seems you just want to give a set role to the user who agrees with the TOS.

Also make sure you have enabled member intents or at least the basic intents which Discord provides. Plus make sure you have the main imports to allow use of Discord utils

```
import discord
import discord.utils
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
```